# Query JSON with SQLAlchemy using the `sqlalchemy.types.JSON` data type

Tags: mysql, json, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have the following table in SQLAlchemy:

```
class FooModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'table'
    id = sqla.Column('id', INTEGER, primary_key=True)
    info = sqla.Column(JSON)
```

And I want to execute the following query:

```
result = session.query(FooModel).filter(
    FooModel.info['key1'].astext.cast(INTEGER) == 1).all()
```

The above query works just fine as long as the `info` column in my table is of type `sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.JSON`. However, if I use `JSON` from `sqlalchemy.JSON` I get the following error: `AttributeError: Neither 'BinaryExpression' object nor 'Comparator' object has an attribute 'astext'`.

Since the above is the most basic filter one can have, does this mean that in order to do any kind of querying you have to use types from a specific SQL dialect? In other words: Is it possible to modify the above query and make it run when I use the sqlalchemy.JSON type? (which will allow the code to work on both PostreSQL and MySQL)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try it as follow

`from sqlalchemy import JSON
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import cast
result = session.query(FooModel).filter(FooModel.info['key1'] == cast(1, JSON).all()`